# Is there a python equivalent to dropwizard metrics?

Tags: python, monitoring, metrics

I am in need of a library/framework where I can handle my application metrics in a centralized way and that allows me to plug in exporters that expose the data to whatever/wherever I need (in my case Carbon and a custom monitoring REST resource). Dropwizard metrics allows you to do this with metric registry and reporters.
I've tried to find a python equivalent, but to no avail. The closest I've come is [AppMetrics](https://pypi.org/project/AppMetrics/), but the latest release was 5 years ago and it's still in Alpha.

Statsd and Prometheus look popular, but I would like to avoid hosting an entire new service for pushing metrics or switch to another time-series database.

Comment: I'd suggest prometheus - you don't need to run a prometheus server at all if you have other tools that can gather from the exporter built into your app, and don't want it's TSDB/alerting capabilities.

Comment: Thanks @match. Looking at https://github.com/prometheus/client_python, I should be able to get what I need using the graphite bridge or writing my own.